# The greatest real number C such that the inequality $|\tan x-\tan y|\geq C|x-y|$ holds for all $x,y \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus

> Find the greatest real number $C$, such that the inequality $$|\tan x-\tan y|\geq C|x-y|$$ holds for all $$x,y \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

All I've done so far is rearranged the inequality $$\bigg|\frac{\tan x-\tan y}{x-y}\bigg| \geq C$$
So since I want this to work for any $x,y$ in the interval I want to minimize $$\bigg|\frac{\tan x-\tan y}{x-y}\bigg|$$ On the interval $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and let that equal $C$. Now this is where I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives and [the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?

Comment: Yes at basic level how would I use the mean value theorem?

Comment: Good. Without loss of generality you can assume $x>y$. Tangent is an increasing function in your interval, so doing that allows you to drop the absolute value signs. MVT says that this ratio is equal to the derivative of tangent at a point $c, y<c<x$. What's the smallest value of $D\tan x$ can have at $x=c$?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand but your saying $\frac{\tan x-\tan y}{x-y}= \sec^{2}c$ and I need the minimum value of $c$ on the interval?

Comment: Yeah I see what you were saying now thanks I got 1 as correct answer

Comment: Great! Well done! The ratio $(\tan x-\tan y)/(x-y)$ is actually always $>1$, but as the derivative is $1$ at $0$, the ratio becomes arbitrarily close to $1$, when both $x$ and $y$ are closer and closer to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MVT (mean value theorem), which @JyrkiLahtonen has mentioned and explained in his/her comment, you can find that, assuming $-\pi/2<x<y<\pi/2$
$$\frac{\tan y-\tan x}{y-x}=\sec^2 \xi\ge1$$
for some $\xi\in(x,y)$, this means that the requested $C$ is at least $1$, namely $C\ge1$. 
Then, fix $x=0$, and we get $\frac{\tan y-0}{y-0}$, which, when $y\to0$, is the derivative of $\tan$ at $0$. Thus $\forall \epsilon>0$, you can always find a $\delta>0$ s.t. 
$$1\le\frac{\tan y-0}{y-0}<1+\epsilon,\,\,\forall y\in(-\delta,0)\cup(0,\delta)$$
which by definition means that
$$\inf_{y\in(-\delta,0)\cup(0,\delta)} \frac{\tan y-0}{y-0}=1$$
Therefore 
$${1}\le C\le\inf_{y\in(-\delta,0)\cup(0,\delta)} \frac{\tan y-0}{y-0}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y=0$  then $\dfrac {|\tan x|} {x}| \ge C$ since

$|\dfrac {\tan x} {x}| \ge 1$ with $1$ being an infimum  then $C \le 1$

Hence we are left to prove inequality for $c=1$

W.L.O.G let $x\ge y$  then since $\tan x -x$  is increasing we have

$\tan x-x \ge \tan y-y \Rightarrow \dfrac {\tan x-\tan y} {x-y} \ge 1$